# Problem with picking up a -Dattribute in Maven using Antrun

Tags: maven-2, maven-antrun-plugin

So I have this snippet in my pom

```
<configuration>  
  <target if="csc" >
    <echo>Unzipping md csc help</echo>
  </target> 
  <target unless="csc">
    <echo>Unzipping md help</echo>
  </target>
</configuration>
```

When I run with mvn normally it correctly executes the unless="csc" target. The problem is that when I run it with -Dcsc=true it does not run any of the targets.

What am I doing wrong? :)

Thanks

Comment: Unzipping can be done without using Ant...

Answer (score 1):

It seems the antrun plugin supports only a single target element in the configuration. You can achieve the same effect with [maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) that get activated when the [property is set or absent](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation-by-absence.html):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>property-set</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>csc</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>antrun-property-set</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <target> 
                                    <echo>property is set</echo>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>property-not-set</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>!csc</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>antrun-property-not-set</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <target> 
                                    <echo>property is not set</echo>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

The unpacking can be done via the [maven-dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html).